# Programmatically generated react state key names

Tags: reactjs

What is the correct way to pass in a variable key name to `setState` in ReactJS? I'm finding myself having to play the temporary map game, a la

```
removeLookup(idx) {
    let lookupPrefix = this.composeKeys(Editor.fooDefinition, "lookups");
    let arraySizeKey = this.composeKeys(lookupPrefix, Editor.arrayLengthKey);
    let lookupCount = this.state[arraySizeKey];

    let newState = new Map();
    newState[arraySizeKey] = lookupCount - 1;
    newState[this.composeKeys(lookupPrefix, Editor.isDeletedKey)] = true;

    this.setState(newState);
}
```

It works, but I'd rather just call `setState` with each modification, instead of building the map upfront, especially in cases where I only have one such modification.

Answer (score 0):

```
You don't have to use map you acn use just an obj.

 var _state = {};
 _state[arraySizeKey] = lookupCount - 1;
 _state[this.composeKeys(lookupPrefix, Editor.isDeletedKey)] = true;
 this.setState(_state);
```

But i think below is what you need you can write variable name in [...]

```
    this.setState({
    [arraySizeKey]: lookupCount - 1,
    [this.composeKeys(lookupPrefix, Editor.isDeletedKey)]:true  
    });
```

Comment: that makes the key an array of string, not a string. noted re: the map.